# Assigning answers - quiz program

Tags: android, mobile, android-intent

I need a way to asssign 3 possible answers to a question in a ArrayList where only one of the answers is correct.

I am new to Android so I appreciate if you could help.

I have a question class here:

```
package com.example.quiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Questions extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> questionsArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    public Questions() {
        addQuestion("Which Prophet was the first in Islam?");
        addQuestion("What is the purpose of life?");
        addQuestion("Who is the last Prophet in Islam?");

    }

    public void addQuestion(String question) {
        questionsArray.add(question);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getQuestionsArray() {
        return questionsArray;
    }

    public void setQuestionsArray(ArrayList<String> questionsArray) {
        this.questionsArray = questionsArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible approaches. One of them is to create an `ArrayList` for each answer option ie A, B and C. Then one more `ArrayList` which indicates which answer is correct

Therefore there will be totally 4 `ArrayList`s, 3 for storing answers and one to indicate which option is correct

Answer (score 0):

Maps are useful when having to associate data with other data. In your case, you are trying to associate questions to arrays of answers for each question.

You can make a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> answers` and retain the answers (the `ArrayList<String>`) for all questions (the `String`), then have another `HashMap<String, String> correctAnswers` where you retain the question (1st `String`) and it's associated correct answer (2nd `String`).

When validating the answer you would have to get the answer that the user has chosen and compare it to the correct answer like this:

```
if(correctAnswers.get(questionString).compareTo(chosenAnswerString))
{
    //correct answer!
}
else
{
    //incorrect answer
}
```

The method used to add a question along with its answers you would become:

```
[...]

private Map answers = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Sting>>();
private Map correctAnswers = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void addQuestion(String question, ArrayList<String> answers, String correctAnswer)
{
   this.answers.put(question, answers);
   this.correctAnswers.put(question, correctAnswer);
}

[...]
```

When creating the `answers` map as above, your map would retain the array of questions, an array of arrays of answers and the association between each question and its answers array.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't look up the javadoc for maps and ended up using a `Collection` method instead. Try using `this.answers.put(question, answers)`. I've updated my answer and corrected the error. +1 for pointing it out